# Spring JPA Repository generating incorrect SQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring JPA Repository with Hibernate below towards a MySQL Database. On that environment, I've the following Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cod__postales")
public class CodigoPostal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long registro;

    @Column(name = "`POST_Nº_CODIGO`", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private String codigo = "  ";

    @Column(name = "POST_DESCRIP", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String descripcion = "                              ";

    @Column(name = "POST_ZONA_ASIG", length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String zona = "  ";
```

Also I've the following Spring JPA Repository:

```
public interface CodigoPostalRepository extends JpaRepository<CodigoPostal, Long> {

    CodigoPostal findOneByCodigo(String codigo);

}
```

As you can see, there isan special character on the first column name 'º'. The problem es that, when I call to **repo.findOneByCodigo()** method, the following SQL is generated

```
select codigopost0_.registro as registro1_2_,
    codigopost0_.`post_nº_codigo` as post_nº_2_2_,
    codigopost0_.post_descrip as post_des3_2_,
    codigopost0_.post_zona_asig as post_zon4_2_
from cod__postales codigopost0_
where codigopost0_.`post_nº_codigo`=?
```

The problem is that sql gives an error because of the name spring/hibernate assing to that column: **as post_nº_2_2_**.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Doesn't really help you (unless you are open to changing your JPA provider), but the implementation I use (DataNucleus) runs fine on that type of query with non-standard characters in the select clause (it doesn't put these needless aliases in its generated SQL)

Answer (score 1):

This is a first thought regarding this query and my suggestion is to introduce a native query which will help you to change '**as post_nº_2_2_.**' in something like: '**as post_n_2_2_.**'.

**Example:**

```
@Query(value = " select codigopost0_.registro as registro1_2_,
    codigopost0_.`post_nº_codigo` as post_n_2_2_,
    codigopost0_.post_descrip as post_des3_2_,
    codigopost0_.post_zona_asig as post_zon4_2_
from cod__postales codigopost0_
where codigopost0_.`post_nº_codigo`=?", nativeQuery = true)
public interface CodigoPostalRepository extends JpaRepository<CodigoPostal, Long> {

    CodigoPostal findOneByCodigo(String codigo);

}
```

More information on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've been able to solve this by adding the characterEncoding parameter to the url string:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/madr?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Anyway, I've opened an issue to Hibernate because maybe this is not a valid option for everyone https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10493

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
@Column(name = "`POST_Nº_CODIGO`", length = 6, nullable = false)
```

to

```
@Column(name = "`POST_N_CODIGO`", length = 6, nullable = false)
```

Comment: I was just checking the same thing.Is it necessary to avoid 'º'?

Comment: It doesn't work. The column POST_N_CODIGO doesn't exist and an exception is raised by Hibernate: o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'post_n_codigo' in 'field list'

Comment: You have to recreate the database to get the new column

Comment: This is a legacy database. That solution is not viable.